# How to set password for zip file in PHP

Tags: php, passwords, zip

This code is work perfectly. But password not set for the .zip file. I don't know why. When saving file its save perfectly to a zip file but password not set for that file. I think some misplacement in code.

```
for ($num = 0; $num < count($fileArray["name"]); $num++) {
    $fileName = $fileArray["name"][$num];
    $tempName = $fileArray["tmp_name"][$num];                                                   
    move_uploaded_file($tempName, "tmp/" . $fileName);}
    $archiveName = rand(10000, 1000000) . ".zip";
    $filesArrayNames = $_FILES["upload_files"]["name"];
    $zipDir = scandir("zip/");
    $error = false;
    foreach ($zipDir as $zipDIrFile) {
        if ($zipDIrFile == $archiveName) {
            $error = true;
            break; 
        }
    }
    if ($error == false) {
        $tmpDir = scandir("tmp/");
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open("zip/" . $archiveName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        $zip->setPassword($password);
        for ($num = 0; $num < count($fileArray["name"]); $num++) {
            $fileName = $fileArray["name"][$num];
            $zip->setEncryptionName($fileArray["name"][$num], ZipArchive::EM_AES_256);
            foreach ($tmpDir as $tmpDirFile){
                if($tmpDirFile == $fileName){
                    $zip->addFile("tmp/".$fileName);
                    // echo 'Adding'.$fileName."<br />";
                    echo $password;
                }
            }
        }
        $zip->close();
        for ($num = 0; $num < count($fileArray["name"]); $num++) {
            $fileName = $fileArray["name"][$num];
            foreach ($tmpDir as $tmpDirFile){
                if($tmpDirFile == $fileName){
                    unlink("tmp/".$fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    } else { 
        echo 'Name already exists';
    }
}
```

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php) for `ZipArchive::setPassword()`: "As of PHP 7.2.0 and libzip 1.2.0 the password is used to decompress the archive, and is also the default password for `ZipArchive::setEncryptionName()` and `ZipArchive::setEncryptionIndex()`. Formerly, this function only set the password to be used to decompress the archive; it did not turn a non-password-protected ZipArchive into a password-protected ZipArchive."

Comment: So you must be using an old version of PHP. (Hint: anything below 7.1 is end-of-life and absolutely should not be used.)

Comment: after removing that part, still the same.

Comment: I'm using  7.3 PHP version